# What is the full name of a function scope type?

Tags: c++

In the following program:

```
int main()
{
  struct my_struct {};
  return 0;
}
```

What is the fully-qualified name of `my_struct`? I realize I cannot refer to `my_struct` outside of `main`, but the name or mangled name of the type may occur in other contexts (e.g., compiler error messages, `typeid`, etc.).

Does the C++ standard mandate a naming scheme for such types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. There is no language-level standard name mangling schema, not even for overloaded functions. All such things are implementation specific. Refer to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that name mangling is implementation defined. I am asking if there is a standard naming scheme for local types.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: And, as this answer says, there is no standard naming scheme. For the examples in your question: compiler error messages are obviously implementation specific, and for `typeid`, `std::type_info::name()` is defined to return "An implementation-defined ntbs" (null terminated byte string) `[type.info]/9`.